# miminum height and width of a div

Tags: jquery

I have a re-sizable and drag able div in my page
I want to restrict users to re size the DIV to a fixed minimum width or height and cannot resiz more than that.

i did try it using the following code but it did not help.
please guide me to solve this.

```
$("#dv_move").resizable({
            resize: function () {
                var t = $(this);
                if (parseInt(t.width()) < 300 || parseInt(t.height()) < 150)
                    return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
    $("#dv_move").resizable({
        minWidth: 300,
        minHeight: 300
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I just Google'd "jquery resizable", clicked the first option, then looked at the "options" tab.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

Specifically, the `minWidth` and `minHeight` options.

It's amazing what you can find if you look.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it works for only one option at a time ie, either width or height, the one which set first